# Как отправить голосовое сообщение через VK API?

Tags: java, vkontakte-api

[Здесь](https://vk.com/dev/messages.send) про это не сказано ровным счётом ничего. В ходе "расследования" скачивал различные клиенты. [Kate mobile](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.perm.kate_new_6) может отправить такое сообщение, но как-то раз я увидел его "голым". Скажем так,  как файл с расширением. С этого момента начал рыть документацию в [этом](https://vk.com/dev/docs) месте и мне кажется, что message.send и docs связаны. Как бы на практике только отправить такое сообщение?

***P. 's.*** То,  что я смог отрыть :

> там все засунули в документы. В полученном URL методом docs.getUploadServer добавляется один параметр, ... не скажу сейчас какой (не помню, кажется, type) равный audio_msg

**Update:**
С помощью сниффинга трафика Kate смог отрыть, что загружается аудио-сообщение путем передачи СКРЫТОГО параметра. Пример:

```
https://api.vk.com/method/docs.getUploadServer?access_token=your_token&type=audio_message&v=5.38
```

**Теперь новая стадия вопроса:**
*Как передать файл голосовой в формате multipart/form-data*

**Update:** Ответ с Tostera (там тоже активчик по такому вопросу):

> Пытался реализовать то же самое, но на питоне, в итоге перепробовав
>   все пришел к выводу, что камнем преткновения становится UUID который
>   присутствует в заголовке "boundary=", а так-же передается сразу перед
>   тем как улетит файл. Подобной дупликации нет при загрузке других
>   документов, там UUID передается однажды.
>   [[Скриншот перехваченого пакета с официального приложения во время отправки аудиосообщения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WenlF.jpg)]

*Кстати, если это важно - из пакета я достал формат файла:*
**Kate**: .3gp   **Официальный клиент**: .ogg/.mp3

Comment: `Как передать файл голосовой в формате multipart/form-data` Вы не знаете, как загружать во ВК документы? Я правильно понимаю вопрос?

Comment: Не совсем. Вообще, это новая стадия вопроса,  но суть в том,  что я незнаю, как передать в этом формате файл. Нашёл методом тыка, что надо,  но вк ругается. Возможно,  Вы подскажете?

Comment: Почему удалил ответ? он не работает?

Comment: Я его доделываю :) Будет большой и красивый. Это случайно опубликовал.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**Троекратное ура!** Ответ найден!
Итак, для того, чтобы загрузить аудио-сообщение на сервера VK, надо:

- Получаем ссылку для загрузки на сервер. **Обратите внимание на
  параметр**:

  > *type=audio_message*

  ```
     https://api.vk.com/method/docs.getUploadServer?access_token=your_token&type=audio_message&v=5.38
  ```
- В ответ нам придет вот такой **JSON**:

  ```
     {"response":{"upload_url":"https:\/\/pu.vk.com\/c806630\/upload.php?act=add_doc&mid=151665536&aid=0&gid=0&type=audio_message&hash=a171e6bf246f389425f23a62ba4165d4&rhash=6e0e444008a2186f484af9f02c2ac49f&api=1"}}
  ```
- Забираем из него URL для загрузки:

  ```
  https://pu.vk.com/c806630/upload.php?act=add_doc&mid=151665536&aid=0&gid=0&type=audio_message&hash=a171e6bf246f389425f23a62ba4165d4&rhash=6e0e444008a2186f484af9f02c2ac49f&api=1
  ```
- Заимствуем код отсюда:

http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/upload-files-by-sending-multipart-request-programmatically

Поясню: здесь мы берем код, который поможет загрузить нам файл на сервера VK в формате **multipart/form-data**, который VK и требует. *Возможные форматы файлов:* **mp3** (Использует официальный клиент), **3gp** (использует Kate)

- В классе **MultipartFileUploader** добавляем поле **"file"**, как того требует VK:

  > Передайте файл на адрес upload_url, полученный в предыдущем пункте,
  >   сформировав POST-запрос с полем file. Это поле должно содержать файл в
  >   формате multipart/form-data.

  ```
  multipart.addFilePart("file", uploadFile1);
  ```
- **Выполняем запрос, ПРОФИТ!**
  Получаем вот такой **JSON** в ответ:

  ```
  "file":"123456|65421|0|415317|20ee43693a|jpg|81897|Document.jpg|6798bc4fe908cc476cb1c13ce844a985|105d984a920fe7ee9042681bb6d30fbd|m_20ee43693a||m:130x72,s:100x55,x:604x331,y:807x442,o:748x409"
  ```
- Далее сохраняем наш документ на сервере VK:

  ```
  https://api.vk.com/method/docs.save?file=ЗДЕСЬ_ПОЛУЧЕННЫЙ_ПАРАМЕТР_ФАЙЛ&access_token=your_token&v=5.60
  ```

И получаем такой **JSON** в ответ:

```
"response": [{
"**id**": 440531838,
"**owner_id**": 151665536,
"title": "comm",
"size": 467756,
"ext": "ogg",
"url": "https://vk.com/do...90e2afaa7&api=1",
"date": 1483295228,
"type": 5,
"preview": {
"audio_msg": {
"duration": 292,
"waveform": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 5, 1, 6, 0, 2, 5, 20, 10, 8, 7, 12, 24, 16, 5, 4, 8, 8, 4, 6, 2, 6, 5, 1, 9, 10, 4, 2, 7, 3, 16, 0, 6, 1, 11, 2, 7, 3, 3, 4, 3, 5, 2, 8, 2, 7, 13, 5, 8, 9, 5, 3, 2, 13, 20, 6, 7, 8, 13, 2, 13, 1, 5, 14, 1, 2, 16, 12, 10, 5, 21, 31, 15, 7, 16, 19, 19, 9, 13, 1, 4, 10, 10, 4, 2, 11, 5, 5, 2, 8, 2, 8, 1, 3, 0, 1, 5, 4, 2, 5, 3, 7, 5, 0, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
"link_ogg": "https://cs540102....udio/b70049db92.ogg",
"link_mp3": "https://cs540102....udio/b70049db92.mp3"
}
}
}]
```

- С помощью метода [messages.send](https://vk.com/dev/messages.send) отправляем наш загруженный файл в виде **doc**:

  ```
  https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?user_id=111111&attachment=doc<owner_id>_<media_id>&access_token=your_token&v=5.60
  ```

> Данные **owner_id** и **media_id** мы получаем из предыдущего пункта

И благополучно получаем в лс аудио-сообщение. Спасибо за внимание!

***P/s Кстати, версия 5.60 тоже работает (проверил), поэтому можно в запросах использовать и её.***

---

**Update:**
Тут возник новый вопрос - как ответить аудио-сообщением юзеру в сообщениях сообщества? Отвечаем-с...

---

**Для группы:**

- Первым делом открываем доступ администраторам к документам группы
  ("ограниченный" режим)
- Потом заходим в настройки сообщества и там берем ключ сообщества
- Дальше делаем такой запрос на загрузку:

  ```
  https://api.vk.com/method/docs.getWallUploadServer?group_id=<gorup_id>&access_token=<group_token>&v=5.60
  ```
- Загружаем файл так, как я показывал выше и сохраняем таким же образом
- Отправляем сообщение юзеру от имени сообщества вот так:

  ```
  https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?user_id=<user_id>&attachment=doc<owner_id>_<audio_id>&access_token=<group_token>&v=5.60
  ```

  **Профит!**

---

**Для публичной страницы:**
Казалось бы, все так просто будет и **публичной страницей**, но не тут-то было. Так как для пабликов не предусмотрены голосовые сообщения и Вам будет отдавать ошибку авторизации,используем небольшой лайфхак..

- ***Переводим наш паблик в группу и обязательно получаем новый ключ уже группы с доступом к документам и аудио***
- Снова переводим группу в паблик
- В меню Управление сообществом -> Настройки -> Разделы ставим галочки на пунктах: **"Ссылки"** и **"Аудиозаписи"**
- Благополучно используем все, что я написал для группы

---

**Ну и немножко веселья:**

- В комменты/на стену/в обсуждения (оказывается), можно отправить **АУДИО-СООБЩЕНИЕ**
  (*вчитайтесь еще раз, пожалуйста*). Делается весьма просто. Обычным
  запросом на отправку в комменты/на стену/в обсуждения. В аттаче прикрепляем наше аудио
  (выглядит действительно как аудио-сообщение, что вызвало вой
  удивления в пабликах, в которых я это тестировал)
- Еще одна замечательная вещь - пустые энтити аудио-сообщений.[image: Выглядит примерно так. Новая веселая фишка!]
    Для отправки вместо формата *doc* в описании **attachment** пишем *audio*
- И снова новый баг. Можно отправить пустое аудио (просто убираем флаг на чтение и отправляем "ничего". Было проверено на Python):
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- Пустые комменты.... ***Magic!***

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Делается так же. При отправке коммента вместо формата *doc* в описании **attachment** пишем *audio*. Заметил, однако, что в разных комментариях баг выглядит по-разному. Где-то без пустого места внутри, а где-то с пустым...
***P/s Кстати, проверил, прокатывает и в обсуждениях. Оставил в группе vk api напоминание :)***
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update:**
Вместо формата аттача doc или audio можно вставить почти что угодно. Хоть вики. Возможно, чем то полезно. Правда, ***photo*** не вставляется...

---

**Update:**
Большие файлы загружать **НЕЛЬЗЯ**! Получим ошибку: 504 Gateway Time-out

---

**Update:**
Техподдержка ответила:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
**Новый ответ**:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Ну и собственно, завершение спектакля**:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update:**
Ну раз тех.поддержка говорит про закрытый AudioAPI, то почему бы его не использовать, пока не прикрыли? Накатал недавно небольшой текст по его использованию. Такой простой доступ был неожиданностью...
 В конце, кстати, приводятся интересные сайты, до сих пор работающие с вк.

[http://telegra.ph/Работа-с-закрытым-VK-API-12-31](http://telegra.ph/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BC-VK-API-12-31)

Comment: Браво! Как насчёт статьи на хабре?

Comment: @СергейГрушин спасибо :) Я бы с удовольствием, да никогда там не писал и незнаю, как оно делается.

Comment: А жаль. Было б отлично)

Comment: @СергейГрушин согласен. Может, когда-нибудь научусь это делать :D А то ещё как пойдут минусы. Хабр -  сообщество нежное.

Comment: :D мне ещё расти до вас) так далеко я ещё не лез никуда) пока торчу на андроиде на списках бд и материал дизайн

Comment: @СергейГрушин да ладно Вам. Я тоже учусь. Этот вопрос я вообщем-то начал рыть, потому что мир не ответил мне :D Оказалось, что это достаточно интересно. Заодно и аудио апи "нагнул" и бота для телеграмма сделал для поиска. Вообщем такая глубина просто была вынужденной :)

Comment: Пришел сюда ток ради этого коммента, искал инфу про api
Троекратное спасибо :3

Comment: @Денис  спасибо :)

Comment: @Flerry, это работает до сих пор? У вас нет unknown errorов? У меня 70% ошибок, 30% успешно загруженных аудио.

Answer (score 1):

Всем привет! API обновилось и изменились некоторые моменты.
Во-первых загрузка mp3 в документы теперь запрещена.
Это выглядит как ответ такой:

```
{ error: 'unknown error' }
```

Во вторых, в адресе для отправки от имени группы пропущены символы:

```
https://api.vk.com/method/docs.getWallUploadServer?group_id=<GID>&access_token=<TOKEN>&v=5.62
```

И, наконец, третья проблема. Все сделал, все работает, но как результат - сам файл, а не голосовое сообщение (я его грузил как *.ogg* или *.opus*). Прошу вашей помощи!

Comment: Следует добавить этот текст в Ваш вопрос, если он Ваш. Или задать свой отдельно. Это сообщение не является ответом.

Comment: вы тип при получении сервера указывали?
type=audio_message

Comment: @Денис в инструкции к посту при отправке от имени группы написано, что не указывается type=audio_message. Если указать, то ссылка на загрузку выдается нормально, но при загрузке файла получаю { error: 'unknown error' }. Пробовал 3 формата - mp3, vaw и ogg - результат одинаковый.. Есть мнение, что файл битый, так что попробую проверить его сейчас.

Comment: Была такая проблема, когда не передавал content-type нужный

Comment: @Денис а какой нужный? для ogg - audio/ogg или audio/opus?

Comment: Вот здесь все подробно описано, https://vk.cc/5UcCdP, я гружу ogg, как и указано в формате multipart/form-data.

Comment: @Денис у вас нормально проигрываются аудиозаписи посланные таким способом на телефоне ?

Comment: @Lolidze, да, когда занимался этим, все хорошо работало. Сейчас не проверял