# Как установить шапку группы через VK API?

Tags: java, vkontakte-api

***Для начала вот, что такое шапка группы:***
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В [документации](https://vk.com/dev/manuals) API не сказано абсолютно ничего про загрузку. Вылазки через неофициальные клиенты больше не помогают, ибо в них такое не реализовано (*отсылка к [этому](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/609865/219079) вопросу*). Путём просмотра запросов, обнаружил, что сигнатура вызовов не похоже не на один метод/способ загрузки файлов, указанный [здесь](https://vk.com/dev/upload_files). Итак, что я смог отрыть из запросов:

1. У каждого файла, загружаемого на шапку, есть **_sig**. Он странным образом меняется от запроса к запросу, но без него нельзя загрузить файл.
2. Если отловить запросы вк, то мы получим статическую ссылку для загрузки файла. Эта статическая ссылка вполне себе работает и при переходе на нее пишет такое:

   ```
   {"error":"ERR_UPLOAD_FILE_NOT_UPLOADED: file not found","bwact":"owner_cover","server":836521,"mid":151665536,"_sig":"83447078c5079124026b80d90f116398"}
   ```

Однако после исполнения загрузки в коде, получаем:

```
{"error":"ERR_UPLOAD_BAD_SIGNATURE","bwact":"owner_cover","server":836521,"_sig":"d762c16dc795c4f65b59aafdaa39628a"}
```

3. Метод, используемый VK (обычно метод виден в параметре **act**. Допустим, при загрузке *аудио-сообщения*, было **add_doc**), в документации отсутствует и выглядит так: **act=owner_cover**.

Comment: эта фича с шапкой в группах появилась относительно недавно, мне кажется API еще не дописали просто

Comment: Ну, возможно... Но все же можно попытаться найти выход. Ибо теперь все, что они делают - в API не заходит. Исключение - реклама. Деньги же стричь надо...

Comment: Есть ли готовое бесплатное решение? не нарушает ли это политику вк?

Comment: @СергейБреславец если хотите задать новый вопрос, опубликуйте его именно как вопрос. Ну и про политику ВК лучше поискать в их пользовательском соглашении.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ура! Ура! Ура! Вопрос снова решен :) Правда, сразу скажу, господа, что тут, намного сложнее, чем то, что я решал раньше - [тык](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/609865/219079).
***Внимание***: ***все запросы мы будем производить с cookie. Без них - никак.***
Вообщем, поехали:

1. **Получаем ссылку для загрузки нашего ковра (в VK шапка называется cover)**:

   - Запрос делаем сюда: `https://vk.com/al_page.php`
   - В headers прикрепляем наши **cookie**
   - В тело **POST**-запроса пишем это: `act=owner_photo_box&al=1&cover=1&oid=-id вашей группы`
   - Если все прошло успешно, получаем примерно такую страницу в ответ:
     [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
   - В конце страницы будут ссылки. Нам нужна первая (идет сразу после **OwnerPhoto.uploadInit**). См. скриншот:
     [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
     Наша ссылка получилась такая: `https:\/\/pu.vk.com\/c837731\/upload.php?act=owner_cover&oid=-136618761&square=&mid=151665536&server=837731&_origin=https%3A%2F%2Fvk.com&_sig=c55042259e8ee7c612cdcd9861961cdf`
2. **Загружаем наше фото на сервера VK, используя ссылку, полученную в предыдущем пункте**:

   Как загрузить файл в формате **multipart/form-data** я описывал [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/609941/219079) (стандартная библиотека Java) или *намного короче и более красиво* можно загрузить с помощью библиотеки **OkHttp** - процесс описан [здесь](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes#posting-a-multipart-request).
   ***ВНИМАНИЕ:*** теперь VK принимает картинки только с полем **file** в post-запросе! Вот так (тут на Java) - multipart.addFilePart("file", uploadFile1);
   Если картинка будет в поле с другим названием, вы получите такую ошибку:

   {"error":"ERR_UPLOAD_FILE_NOT_UPLOADED: file not found","bwact":"owner_cover","server":638219,"mid":151665536,"_sig":"9417bfeb4cca32304ed587818d931931"}

В ответ получим описание нашей фотки в таком формате:

```
`{"oid":"-136618761","photo":{"photo":"6fae155614x","sizes":[["x","837731536","18af4","9lzKWBYrE2w",795,1060],["y","837731536","18af5","8knjXW2i2K8",810,1080],["o","837731536","18af6","-w20s8JJGNA",810,1080]],"kid":"9d20ccbaa7b6ec6d7171716dcd5bade1","debug":"xxoyooo"},"x_src":"v837731536\/18af4\/9lzKWBYrE2w.jpg","x_size":[795,1060],"size":[810,1080],"bwact":"owner_cover","server":837731,"mid":151665536,"_sig":"fe9a46f1b2e26f4a1c56bbc36850a10e"}`
```

3. **Сохраняем наше произведение искусства**:

   - Берем первую часть нашей ссылки, полученной в первом пункте с номером сервера, и подставляем к ней **act=owner_cover_crop&_query=** и **описание нашей фотки**, полученное из пункта выше. В нашем случае выглядит так:

   `https://pu.vk.com/c837731/upload.php?act=owner_cover_crop&_query={"oid":"-136618761","photo":{"photo":"2b522d8e86x","sizes":[["x","837731536","18aa5","tuY07_54Ovk",795,497],["y","837731536","18aa6","RxPs7YD5hCs",1590,994],["o","837731536","18aa7","nmZ4LwQDbgw",2880,1800]],"kid":"621fad611afefb9048b478bcc627ab12","debug":"xxoyooo"},"x_src":"v837731536\/18aa5\/tuY07_54Ovk.jpg","x_size":[795,497],"size":[2880,1800],"bwact":"owner_cover","server":837731,"mid":151665536,"_sig":"efb64dcfd413f8e1cd52c86c9ffe98d6"}`
   ***Это наш URL, к которому будем обращаться.***

   - В header обязательно вставляем наши **cookie**
   - Ответ получим такой:

   `{"oid":"-136618761","data":["xAAzIYwAAAAAx7sTQAAGK9PZcylgWKxNsYAAGK9fJJ411totivOAAGK9vsNtLPCSRjQAAAGK91LwRyB-lQoPBAAGK-LTMIdOtvbDACAAGK-W1AR45kIrfADAAGK-n6SOgL5ttKpEAAGK-6ApZsVYFCSa","0,0,795,200",0,"810,1080","795,1060"],"bwact":"owner_cover_crop","server":837731,"mid":151665536,"_sig":"7e008ee2a25eaafe4921763ee3b3691d"}`
4. **Заставляем VK повиноваться и вставить нашу многострадальную картинку в шапку**:

   - Делаем запрос на этот адрес: `https://vk.com/al_page.php`
   - Обязательно в headers вставляем **cookie**
   - В тело **POST**-запроса вставляем строку, полученную в пункте выше и добавляем перед ней **_query=**, а после нее - **&act=owner_photo_save&al=1&from=groups**. Выглядеть тело будет так:

   `_query={"oid":"-136618761","data":["xAAzIYwAAAAAx7sTQAAGKnqTNf2fQ6fuoYAAGKn3Z9dX-ImPaLOAAGKoG1FCgvWBDhHAAAGKqJRsM9D7RwUzBAAGKqWp6mu7odOTZCAAGKqsVKNMJ80uh9DAAGKq99X4PZhrf1wEAAGKrFjQIUH8hRcw","0,536,2880,724",0,"2880,1800","795,497"],"bwact":"owner_cover_crop","server":837731,"mid":151665536,"_sig":"3aeeb1dff8888aed8bf8f65c91568bb0"}&act=owner_photo_save&al=1&from=groups`

*Следите за разрешением фото, когда будете его загружать. Если не подойдет - VK начнет обрезать, но вы можете в запросах указать размеры (думаю, понятно где и как). Вообще, VK рекомендует **1590×400**...*

***Спасибо за внимание! Надеюсь кому-то помог...***

Comment: Но однажды это всё сломается)

Comment: @andreymal Врятли. Если конечно API не появится.

Answer (score 2):

Недавно появились методы API для этого:

- [photos.getOwnerCoverPhotoUploadServer](https://vk.com/dev/photos.getOwnerCoverPhotoUploadServer)
- [photos.saveOwnerCoverPhoto](https://vk.com/dev/photos.saveOwnerCoverPhoto)

Вызываем первый метод (там нас просят выбрать область для обрезки, если указать не пропорциональное 795x200, будет вырезан верх выбранной области), загружаем файл по полученной ссылке, передаём полученные hash и photo во второй метод — шапка обновлена.