# Как загрузить обложку группы вк?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Для программы потребовалось загружать обложку сообщества в вк, но я не могу найти метод в документации. Кто знает, как это сделать?

Comment: нету метода (((

Comment: гляньте http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/614998/183314

Comment: Ага, на дубликат вопроса по ссылке выше тянет. Метода нет, но в̶ы̶ ̶д̶е̶р̶ж̶и̶т̶е̶с̶ь̶ можно обход накостылять

Comment: Ссылка-то конечно полезная, но можно код пожалуйста, у меня что-то не работает(

Comment: У меня b'<!--845867348558<!><!>0<!>6760<!>3<!>6db65fee8ee307d0eb' выдает(

Comment: @mymedia Не работает(

Comment: @user235381, сочувствую

Comment: @mymedia можно код который РАБОТАЕТ?

Comment: @user235381, у меня нету такого. В принципе, можете заказать где-нибудь на fl.ru или подобных сайтах

Answer (score -1):

## Загрузка обложки сообщества

Допустимые форматы: JPG, PNG, GIF. 
Ограничения: минимальный размер фото — 795x200px, сумма высоты и ширины не более 14000px, файл объемом не более 50 МБ. Рекомендуемый размер: 1590x400px.

#### Получение адреса

Вызовите метод [photos.getOwnerCoverPhotoUploadServer](https://vk.com/dev/photos.getOwnerCoverPhotoUploadServer), чтобы получить адрес для загрузки фото. Необходимо указать координаты обрезки фотографии в параметрах **crop_x**, **crop_y**, **crop_x2**, **crop_y2**.

#### Передача файла

Передайте файл на адрес **upload_url**, полученный в предыдущем пункте, сформировав POST-запрос с полем **photo**. Это поле должно содержать изображение в формате multipart/form-data.

После успешной загрузки сервер возвращает в ответе JSON-объект с полями **hash** и **photo**:

> {"hash":"402784f0ec814632ac","photo":"eyJvaWQiOi0zNzI3MzTUsMjAwIiwwLCIxNjgwLDEwNTAiLCI3OTUsNDk3Il0sImJ3YWN0Ijoib3duZXJfY292ZXIiLCJzZXJ2ZXIiOjYzODYyOSwibWlkIjoyMzE0ODUyLCc4MSwiZGF0YSI6WyJ4QUFtLXBRQUFBQUFtRUxmY0FBS3A2VEh4bU5WYmJKOG5ZQUFLcDZ2VkMtWjRVMXdmbk9BQUtwNnnMXVvUGdxYkNBQUtwN21nSGJwQlJJdnMxRhpdWM5bldkRktwQUFBS3A3R1NhdFptbFJWNlNCQUFLcDdVamJEFBS3A3NUktQnJTSHotS0hFQUFLcDhLVVRTbzA4VURpTSIsIjAsMCw3OJfc2lnIjoiNjNkNmQ5NmY1ZmI0NWFiYzdjYjZjMjliOGM5NWNhNWMifQ"}

#### Сохранение результата

Чтобы сохранить фотографию, вызовите метод [photos.saveOwnerCoverPhoto](https://vk.com/dev/photos.saveOwnerCoverPhoto), передав параметры **hash** и **photo**, полученные на предыдущем этапе.

Comment: Вот бы ещё примерчик кода в ответ поместить…