# Как отправить голосовое сообщение через VK API .62?

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Единственная инфа, которая есть в интернете [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/609865/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-vk-api).
По тому способу делаю голосовое сообщение из группы, но в ответ приходит именно документ. Естественно, в документации нечего нет на тему отправки голосовых сообщений. Метод должен работать, сам я подозреваю, что дело в формате файла (я использовал ogg).

Answer (score 1):

Нет, дело было не в формате файла: просто этот метод, во-первых, не был в общем доступе, а во-вторых, с ним всё не так просто. Я [описывал в статье](https://habrahabr.ru/post/327280/) тонкости этого процесса: нужно получить сервер для загрузки документа с ключом доступа пользователя, затем загрузить документ на сервер опять же с ключом доступа пользователя, и сохранять в свой список документов (видно его всё равно не будет) тоже с ключом доступа пользователя. А вот отправлять уже нужно будет с ключом доступа сообщества, причем если пользователь не был администратором сообщества, вместо голосового сообщения придут 3 точки.

Буквально пару дней назад выкатили обновление: теперь (во избежание капч и прочего) документы в диалогах загружаются как бы от имени адресата, и загружаются они прямо в диалог: https://vk.com/dev/docs.getMessagesUploadServer, и теперь оно должно работать нормально и с ключом доступа сообщества.